# stoi throwing error when reading from csv file c++

Tags: c++, csv

I need help trying to read from a csv file.

the layout of my csv is the following

---

1   bob   1   2   11   3   4   5   6  6

2   jane  2   2   11   3   4   5   6  6

and so on

this is how I was trying to read from it

```
std::ifstream file;
    Data d;
    std::vector<Data> values;
    std::string number, name;
    file.open("Data-Organisation-Test1.csv");
    while (file.good())
    {
        getline(file,number,',');
        getline(file,name,',');
        //std::cout<< typeid(number).name();
        int num = stoi(number);
        d.num = num;
        d.name = name;
        // go through all fields
        values.push_back(d);
        
        
    }
```

problems I am facing:

i get the following error when using stoi()

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi
```

when I output the datatype of the variable number it returns 's'
secondly because of this im not sure if i am going about it right of what i am trying to achieve.

this is what i am trying to achieve:

```
struct Data{
int number;
std::string name;
 // ...
}

read from csv file and get reach column and place into struct ie:
getline(file,number,',');
getline(file,name,',');
d.number = number;
d.name = name;
 ...
```

I am also getting a return value of 3

EDIT: this is the closest i have gotten to it to work

```
while (!inFile.eof()) {
    getline ( inFile, number, ',' );
    getline ( inFile, name, ',' );
    getline ( inFile, mark, ',' );
    getline ( inFile, raw, ',' );
    std::cout << "number: " << number <<  std::endl;
    std::cout << "name: " << name<<  std::endl;
    std::cout << "mark: " << mark<<  std::endl;
    std::cout << "raw: " << raw<<  std::endl;
}
```

this outputs correct for the first row and every other row is off by one
ie:

output:

```
number: 1 
name: A
mark: 2
raw: 13
2
number: b
mark: 3
raw: 14
3
weight: c
number: 4
name: 11
```

Comment: Well the exception is the defined behavior of [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) if it's presented with something that's not an "integer".

Comment: As for the reason behind the exception being thrown, I'm guessing it's because of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) Your loop `while (file.good())` suffers from the exact same problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so i should be doing something like while (getline(file,number,',') && getline(file,number,',')  ... ?

Comment: Your example doesn't have any commas or an `s`. Is that just an oversight when you added the data here? Is it failing on the first line or later? It would help to see the actual data it is failing on.

Comment: I would rather recommend you read a *full* line from the file (yes, with `while (getline(file, full_line))`) and then put that line into a `std::istringstream` that you then can parse with e.g. `getline(line_stream, number, ',')`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude could i please more info
i tried it like this in my edit post but got a new error as mentioned

Comment: please edit last edit

Comment: Is `raw` supposed to be the rest of the line? Then don't use the `','` as the separator.